# grails bind selected checkboxes to class object

Tags: java, grails, data-binding

i have generated a list of checkboxes ah shown below

```
 <g:each in="${userReportModelList}"
        var="report" status="i">
        <g:checkBox name="UserReport" id="${report.userReport.parameter.id}" value="${report.userReport.id}"
            checked="${report.isSelected}"
            onclick="checkSelectedCheckBoxes(this.id)" />
        ${report.userReport.parameter.description}
        <br>
    </g:each>
```

userReportModelList is the list of class UserReportModel.

```
List<UserReportModel> userReportModelList = new ArrayList<UserReportModel>();
```

and userReportModel class is as follow

```
public class UserReportModel {
 UserReport userReport = new UserReport();
 boolean isSelected = false;
```

}

i have populated the list and checkboxes are generating successfully.now i want to save the selected checkboxes only from list by binding them to UserReportModel.The only issue i am facing is how to bind the multiple checkboxes to UserReportModel class.kindly help regarding binding of data to this class.

any help is really appreciated.Thanks

Comment: Try changing the name of the checkbox to reports.$i.isSelected or just reports.$i . Then you can easily iterated over params.reports in your controller.